# How can I do task below? What do I have to start from?

Tags: typescript

I got interesting task from my colleague, but I never dealt with same.

So, provided the following string expression:
sum != 5 and (`status = "New"` or `status = "Resolved"`)

I need to implement a function in TypeScript which accepts the string as an argument and returns an Object of type `ConditionFilter<T>`, need to define `ConditionFilter<T>` type and subtypes.

I can assume that the string can be parsed by whitespaces.

```
type ConditionFilter<T> = //TODO

function parseCondition(condition: string): ConditionalFilter<T>{
  //TODO
}
```

What do I have to start from? What should I read? I'm beginner, please won't minus my post.

Comment: Honestly it's not really clear to me what your endgoal is here.
What exactly is ConditionFilter supposed to define?
What is the parse condition function supposed to do?

Comment: Please consider reviewing the guidelines for [ask] A Good Question; the title should probably be more descriptive of your actual problem, and the body of your post should be more explicit about what the desired input/output relationship is supposed to be.  Right now it's too broad and ill-defined for me to have any suggestion at all.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like `predicate`. You can send lambda expression instead of string (It isn't good idea to make expression as string).

So you can define `delegate` type in Typescript like this:

```
type Predicate<T> = (item: T) => boolean;

function parseCondition1<T>(predicate: Predicate<T>, item:T): boolean {
  if(predicate(item))
      return true;
  else
     return false;
}

let string = "test";
console.log(parseCondition1<string>(t=>t == "test", "string"));//false;

let sum = 5;
console.log(parseCondition1<number>(t=>t != sum, 5));//false

enum MYstatus {
    New,
    Resolved
}

let state:MYstatus = MYstatus.New

console.log(parseCondition1<MYstatus>(t=>t == MYstatus.New, state));//true
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=75&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBACgJygEwJYGMCGIoB4AqAfDALwwAUqOAtgFwz4CUpxARgPbsA2UmAdgG5gwAGYBXPuhCp2fGBEwIAzlADCstNNkBGAoXIQkaLDnqIUGbHiIAaGFSh0m9Dt15yA3sBj2RBo5Y4lDSMjN4+EUggYghyIAhiUEI+UFwq4ZFQ0bEwIphpScAAvsI8IDBK8ah8AOakMABEOJUNQuiySm4AdFzsNQaKKup8mjJ8upUI1TX6ICSE5SRkTVAtdg2T0w2hAgD0u3kFQsBlFWLU9QCsbR3dvf0KymoaVGO6fOesUAiz8+UAhGQlOc7JcdvtDulgFAPhcALIATUq2DEShgXgiMAAclAAO42DIwABKq24ADcUMVSlkKiArLREcjomiyIy6cyujjccJ2nxOjwen0Bk9hqMdLg2SilL8FqRWUj2ajOXi7EyoODdvFEsAgA)